# Jumping of a sticky footer in the mobile chrome on a page with a lot of swipers

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, swiper.js, sticky-footer

I have a project with a lot of image content, and in the mobile design there are a lot of blocks with photos and swiper functionality https://swiperjs.com. In the chrome browser on mobile devices when there are a lot of elements with swiper, footer with fixed position starts jumping up and down in the moment of hiding or showing of the address bar.
Gif with the bug on mobile: https://giphy.com/embed/PJ4sLlwts4ziBbCqcX
..on tablet: https://giphy.com/gifs/ZvVenstP3fTHtKlqGs

There are no problems in other browsers like Safari on iPhone or Samsung Internet (which has the same feature with hiding of the address bar) on Android mobile.
Gif with Samsung Internet: https://giphy.com/gifs/AALHRFlsn9Ow7WrtMK

I suppose the problem exists because of the lag in the rendering of a complex html structure or heavy js-processing like hidding of pictures and maybe this is not exactly a problem of swiper lib. But this problem appears only in the mobile chrome.

I also see the similar problem on instagram which uses "swiper" functionality:
https://giphy.com/gifs/QU8RECMfJG0OR7GO2h
But it's not so visible as in my case.

css of footer:

```css
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

I tried `position: sticky`, but it didn't help.

I've made a live example: https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/wCEUiMEmUD3f2B9u/ (https://plnkr.co/edit/wCEUiMEmUD3f2B9u) and angular repo: https://github.com/xfuturomax/swiper-fixed-footer-demo
Styles and html were taken from the demo code: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/demos/010-default.html

Have you got any ideas how I can fix this problem?

---

UPDATE:

1. I've tried like this: https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/
   `top: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100 - 44px);` +

```
    let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
    });
```

but it didn't help

2. I've noticed that even without the footer I see some lag on hiding address bar: https://giphy.com/gifs/iNQGGynwTdrmB8zRPB , where green - background of html tag.

```css
html {
  background-color: green;
}
```

3. One of the solutions - inner scroll on main wrapper, it works well, but address bar now doesn't hide on scroll. This is the only solution at the moment.

```
@media (max-width: 895px) {
      html {
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        position: fixed;
        overflow-y: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      }

      .main-wrapper {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem now. Have you already solve it?

Comment: No, I haven't, I just moved the panel from footer to the header, so now we have two panels at the top position in our site. I think this is a bug of mobile version of Chrome, because I saw this "thing" on all the sites with the swiper functionality (instagram, airbnb - just the same "animation" as I have)

Comment: No, nothing has changed since my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the `.footer`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Okay ill check my old code and update you. I remember i had this problem and i fixed it somehow.

Comment: Didn't work for me either.