# Page jumping during homepage scrolling with SWIPER on mobile android

Tags: javascript, angular, mobile, swiper.js

I use swiper in my angular homepage and during its scrolling with finger (on mobile) the page jump or bounce a little. It happens when I put away the finger after scrolling. I checked that it happen only when swiper is enabled and the same effect occurs in an empty angular application with no special styles. Also it`s hard to debug because I noticed no events in swiper during page scrolling.
The .ts code is as follow:

```
import SwiperCore, { Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay } from 'swiper/core';

SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Autoplay]);
```

.html

```
 <swiper [slidesPerView]="1" [spaceBetween]="30" [loop]="true" [navigation]="true" [pagination]="{clickable: true}"
        [autoHeight]="true" [autoplay]="{
            delay: 4500,
            disableOnInteraction: true
          }" class="mySwiper ">
 <ng-template swiperSlide>
...
 </ng-template>
 <ng-template swiperSlide>
...
 </ng-template>
 <ng-template swiperSlide>
...
 </ng-template>
</swiper>
```

.scss:

```
@import "~swiper/swiper";
@import "~swiper/components/navigation/navigation";
@import "~swiper/components/pagination/pagination";

.mySwiper{
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
.swiper-container {
    width: 100%;
    z-index:0;
  }
  
  .swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

The problem occurs only on mobile (I checked only on smartphones with android). Browsers I checked: chrome and opera.
How to avoid page jumping while scrolling using swiperjs?
[Codesanbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/d9kes)

[Similar problem on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67469565/4510954)

Comment: I check your demo on my Android 11 Phone with Chrome. There is no jumping.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the address bar appearing/disappearing. I also experience the jumping but only when the direction of scrolling has changed, so also as the address bar has its visibility state changed. Were you able to solve the issue?